# What is relation between WPF and Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight

These both are same or different ?

How to develop silverlight in visual studio 2008 ?

**UPDATE**
Please also answer 
How to develop silverlight application in visual studio 2008 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both WPF and Silverlight uses what is called `XAML` to define what the interface / GUI should look like. WPF and Silverlight are both Presentation Layers used on different areas.

WPF is used for Windows based applications whereas Silverlight is used for Web based applications.

Read this blog post about ["When should I use WPF vs Silverlight?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2008/05/06/when-should-i-use-wpf-vs-silverlight.aspx) over at MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. But we can develop web based application in WPF as using WPFBrowserApplication template (VS2008).

Comment: Yes you can use XBAP applications to run it within internet explorer. But silverlight is cross-browser supported. You can se silverlight as an alternative to flash.

Answer (score 1):

You can think about Silverlight like a subset of WPF, but there is one main difference. WPF uses full .Net Framework and Silverlight uses different dlls (so you can't use all classes from .Net framework in SL).

Of course Silverlight is a presentation technology that you use to create browser base application (SL can be also an out of browser application) and WPF is used to create windows applications.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight's original code name was WPF/E with the E standing for "Everywhere". That should help understand the origin of it.

It was designed a a reduced and portable version of WPF, but now both seem to diverge a bit. Here is a good article on how they diverge: [WPF Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925.aspx)